# Two servers each for HTML and Java Jersey Rest APIs or Single Tomcat Webapp

Tags: java, html, rest, tomcat, design-patterns

This is a question to design my dynamic website. It should have a java REST APIs beckend and static HTML view.

- Should I keep my HTML content in separate server(like AWS S3) and REST APIs in Tomcat(hosted in a EC3 instance)

**OR**

- Should I keep index.jsp as my starting point of application. Thus making both HTML and JAVA sit together in the same project. And If I do take this option, will I be able to use Angular and Bootstrap with this or not.

Hope you understood the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I will advice to deploy dynamic content on the Tomcat app server and static content (HTML, images, CSS) on Apache web server. I wouldn't keep static content on s3. It being on Apache gives a lot of advantages like - using Apache server you can compress, cache, authenticate, throttle your static content.

The static and dynamic code can be together in the same project and repo. The devops build process can build jar and war and deploy them separately.

Comment: In that case I will need two machines as HTTP works on port 80 and both servers can't have same port.

Comment: You can use 1 machine 2 ports. Or use 2 machines same port. It doesn't matter because port numbers are configurable.

Comment: How about keeping whole static code outside into different project and then doing what you told?

Comment: That is fine too. Choose the project structure based on your team distribution. If you have 2 different teams, different release cycle then 2 projects make more sense.